# How can a JSP page list two different beans in the same table?

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, taglib

I have a `.jsp` page with this code:

```
<tbody>
    <c:forEach items="${companies}" var="companies">
        <tr>
            <td>${companies.id}</td>
            <td>${companies.name}</td>
            <td>${companies.email}</td>
            <td>${companies.countryId}</td>
            <td>${companies.sendToIdes}</td>
            <td>${companies.senderId}</td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</tbody>
```

and this code:

```
<tbody>
    <c:forEach items="${countries}" var="countries">
        <tr>
            <td>${countries.id}</td>
            <td>${countries.code}</td>
            <td>${countries.name}</td>
            <td>${countries.model}</td>
            <td>${countries.hctaId}</td>
            <td>${countries.certificate}</td>
            <td>${countries.signature}</td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</tbody>
```

See that `companies` has `countryId` and `countries` has `id`, they are related with those 2 informations.

I need to insert a `countries.name` inside my `companies` related with `id` and `countryId`.

Comment: well... whats your probelm? what have oyu tried?

Comment: I want to insert a countries.name inside my companies table, the countries.name should be related with the companies.countryId and country.id

Comment: If you do it in the JSP you have no option but to iterate through your countries for every company. It would be better to add a country name property to your company object and populate that in your controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `countries` is a *map* indexed by country ID (i.e. `country.id`), `${countries[company.countryId].name}` would refer to the country name in the companies table.

(By the way, I recommend that you use a singular variable name in your `c:forEach` variable declaration.  For example, change `var="companies"` to `var="company"` and `var="countries"` to `var="country"`.)